# Using FacetWP and wanting to hide extra facets until the first one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facetwp

So using facetWP I see how you can hide the results template until you have selected a facet by setting up CSS with an additional class that you add once something is selected.

I wanted to also hide 3 out of the 4 facets until someone has made a selection from the first one. So I've tried to adapt that code without any luck.

```
<script>
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.facetwp-dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
    if (selectedOption === 'become-part-of-a-brand' || 'buy-an-existing-business'|| 'self-help-components-approach') {
      $('.facetwp-facet-business_area').addClass('visible');
      $('.facetwp-facet-activity').addClass('visible');
      $('.facetwp-facet-star_rating').addClass('visible');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

This obviously has the corresponding CSS:

```
.facetwp-facet-opportunity_area {display: block;}
.facetwp-facet-business_area {display: none;}
.facetwp-facet-business_area.visible {display: block;}
.facetwp-facet-activity {display: none;}
.facetwp-facet-activity.visible {display: block;}
.facetwp-facet-star_rating {display: none;}
.facetwp-facet-star_rating.visible {display: block;}
```

I know I'm missing something blindingly obvious but Javascript is not my strong point... basically, as soon as the dropdown that I'm referencing changes to any other value then I want the class addition to trigger so they become visible...

Any help would be gratefully received.

Cheers all,

Rob.

EDIT:

I also tried the following:

```
    add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    ?>
    <script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).on('facetwp-loaded', function() {
        if (FWP.loaded) {
          $('.facetwp-template').addClass('visible');
          $('.facetwp-facet-business_area').addClass('visible');
          $('.facetwp-facet-activity').addClass('visible');
          $('.facetwp-facet-star_rating').addClass('visible');
        }
      });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
    }, 100 );[/code]
```

But that doesn't work either... (this edit is to help Multani who asked below...

Comment: Can you please share the HTML as well?

Comment: It's a wordpress site... I didn;t write any HTML. I used this guide https://facetwp.com/how-to-hide-the-template-until-facets-are-selected/ to help me hide the template until I selected any facet but actually I want to limit the facets so only the first is displayed until the user has selected...

Comment: I actually tried the following based on their code above as well:
    add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    ?>
    <script>
    (function($) {
        $(document).on('facetwp-loaded', function() {
        if (FWP.loaded) {
          $('.facetwp-template').addClass('visible');
          $('.facetwp-facet-business_area').addClass('visible');
          $('.facetwp-facet-activity').addClass('visible');
          $('.facetwp-facet-star_rating').addClass('visible');
        }
      });
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
    }, 100 );

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to get the formatting to work in comments...

Comment: I've added the alternative code I tried which was a direct edit of the code at the link I gave...

Comment: Basically, each facet is shown in a <div> with the corresponding CSS class above and all I want is for the CSS to be updated to add the .visible class so those items show. This works fine for the template but not the facets.